# React native EXPO / while installing sketch npm all are showing RNSketch error

Tags: react-native, expo

```
requireNativeComponent: "RNSketch" was not found in the UIManager.
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/getNativeComponentAttributes.js:30:4 in getNativeComponentAttributes
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeViewConfigRegistry.js:102:25 in exports.get
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4097:40 in createInstance
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15835:12 in completeWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19409:28 in completeUnitOfWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19380:30 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
* [native code]:null in renderRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
* [native code]:null in runRootCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21822:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23042:20 in ReactNativeRenderer.render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:52:52 in renderApplication
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:116:10 in runnables.appKey.run
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:197:26 in runApplication
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:645:36 in warningWithoutStack
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18056:16 in callback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7595:16 in callCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7639:19 in commitUpdateEffects
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7630:22 in commitUpdateQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17116:10 in commitLifeCycles
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20002:23 in commitLayoutEffects
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19768:10 in commitRootImpl
* [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19590:4 in commitRoot
* [native code]:null in commitRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
* [native code]:null in runRootCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21822:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23042:20 in ReactNativeRenderer.render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:52:52 in renderApplication
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:116:10 in runnables.appKey.run
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:197:26 in runApplication
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 1):

This module is not on android and if you are using expo , you need to detach it to pure react native . Please see the below link too [rn-skecth](https://github.com/jgrancher/react-native-sketch#notes):

[image]